# asp.net mvc accessing the variables in your application one hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, design-patterns, linq-to-sql

```
 public static class WebConfig
 {     
    private static IList<SystemConfigs> sysconfkeys;
    static WebConfig()
    {         
        sysconfkeys = systemconfigrep.GetAllSystemConfig();
    }

    private static string _SMTPPort = "";
    public static string SMTPPort
    {
        get
        {
            return _SMTPPort = sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPPort") != null ? sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPPort").metavalue : "25";
        }
    }

    private static string _SMTPUsername = "";
    public static string SMTPUsername
    {
        get
        {
            return _SMTPUsername = sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPUsername") != null ? sysconfkeys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.metakey == "SMTPUsername").metavalue : "";
        }
    }
}
```

usage: WebConfig.SMTPUsername;

at present: i am using the system level variable in the above way all over my system in my views or controllers . but the problem above is that static constructor is being called only once initally. if the SMTPUsername is changed the new SMTPUsername will not be reflected in the system. i have to restart the iis pool to make it call once again.

what i want: is to develop a mechanism that will make a database hit when the certain variable is changed. if nothing is change then access the already fetched variables .can some one give some insight about that, any recommended way in asp.net mvc.

what i am thinking to do is to implement cache. but what is the appropriate manner in which i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [SqlDependecyCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)